# Javascript find dictionary items whose key matches a substring in an optimized way

Tags: javascript

Consider the below scenario

```js
const searchString = 'Gen';

const myDict = {
'Genesis': 'You are the beginning',
'Joel': 'Joe is cool'
 // Many other key value pairs
}
```

I need to get `You are the beginning` because searchString(`Gen`) is a substring of `Genesis`.

How can I achieve this in an optimized way in JS?

Comment: how would you do it in a not so optimized way? what have you tried? what goes wrong?

Comment: You could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value and slightly modify some of the solutions

Comment: @NinaScholz I had done it like this ```for (const key in myDict) {
  if (key.includes(searchString)) {
    console.log(myDict[key]);
  }
}```

Comment: @Nuthan, what is bad about this?

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm looping through the entire keys of the dictionary and checking if it includes the substring which defeats the purpose of having a dictionary(O(1) lookup)

Comment: the idea of hashes is to have that hash, not a part of it.

Comment: What should happen when the searchString is found in more than one key of myDict?

Comment: @James I don't have a case where the searchString is found in more than one key of myDict. Mapping of searchString to key of myDict is 1:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const searchString = 'Gen';

const myDict = {
'Genesis': 'You are the beginning',
'Joel': 'Joe is cool'
 // Many other key value pairs
}

const result = Object.entries(myDict).find(([k]) => k.includes(searchString));

console.log(result[1]);
```

Comment: While reading up on Object.entries, I also found Object.keys where you can spare the destructuring. ```const key = Object.keys(myDict).find((key) => key.includes(searchString));
console.log(myDict[key]);```

Comment: Can you please add some description or explaination around your code? It'll be helpful for the future readers to understand the algorithm you've used in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
const searchString = 'Gen';

const myDict = {
'Genesis': 'You are the beginning',
'Joel': 'Joe is cool'
 // Many other key value pairs
}


for (let key in myDict){
    if(key.includes(searchString)){
        console.log(myDict[key]) // You are the beginning
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find()`

```js
const searchString = 'Gen';

const myDict = {
'Genesis': 'You are the beginning',
'Joel': 'Joe is cool'
 // Many other key value pairs
}

const result = Object.entries(myDict).find(([k]) => k.includes(searchString));

console.log(result[1]);
```