# Getting key of Object from Value that is an Object

Tags: javascript, object

I have seen multiple other questions about how to do this, but I am yet to find one that accounts for this scenario.

I have an object (lets call it `obj`), which has object properties (lets call them `objProp`). I need to find the key of an `objProp` so I can delete it from `obj`. I run into an issue because I cannot use `indexOf` or [anything like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value) because my values *are* objects themselves.

```js
//obj declaration etc 

delete obj[getKeyByValue(obj, objProp)];

function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
};
```

the above will not work because `objProp` is another object, is there another way this can be done?

Comment: The link you provided as "anything like this" - top answer, third example. JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ECMAScript Specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) `===` will always return `false` when you compare 2 different objects.

If the order of your objects'(and all inside nested objects) key are the same, `JSON.stringify(object[key]) === JSON.stringify(value)` may work.

Otherwise, consider something like Lodash's [_.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual). Either use it directly by introducing lodash as a dependency or implement something similar by your own.

Comment: since my objects were in the same layout, this worked