# JavaScript finding the index of an array given a substring of entry

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following array

```
data = [
{message:'hello there my name is'},
{message:'this is a test'}
]
```

I am trying to find an index of this array given a variable like such

```
const toFind = 'hello there'
```

Thus the expected return would be an index of `[0]`.

I was looking for something with the effect of `IndexOf()` or `includes()`, but I am not sure how to incorporate this into looping the array and finding a substring of the text.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try some of the solutions provided in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value

Comment: `const index = data.findIndex(v => v.message.includes(toFind))`, *not listed in closed answer*